# Can I define an ordered mixed message array in proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

I want to define in proto3 an ordered list of unrelated classes (messages) like this:

1. Frog
2. Dirt
3. Air
4. Computer 1
5. Computer 2
6. Politics

Is it possible? I can also live with having a base class (base message) if that exists in proto3... Its not clear to mean if the feature set of proto3 allows this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way of representing this would be

```proto
message Wrapper {
    oneof Thing {
        Frog frog = 1;
        //...
        Politics politics = 6;
    }
}
```

and use `repeated Wrapper` for the list/array. There is no one-step `repeated oneof`.

Alternatively, you could just use

```proto
repeated Frog frogs = 1;
//...
repeated Politics politics = 6;
```

However this second layout cannot preserve the order between different kinds of element.

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful.